# Amplify No pubsub module applied for subscription ReactJs

Tags: aws-amplify, graphql-subscriptions, amplifyjs

I am facing issue with subscriptions its throw exception

```
No pubsub module applied for subscription
```

index.js

```
import Amplify from "@aws-amplify/core";
import PubSub from "@aws-amplify/pubsub";
import API from "@aws-amplify/api";
import config from "./aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(config);
PubSub.configure(config);
API.configure(config);
```

my Component

```
async componentDidMount() {
  API.graphql(graphqlOperation(subscriptions.ticketModified)).subscribe({
      next: todoTicket => console.log(todoTicket)
    });
}
```

what I am missing?

Comment: Please attach full exception msg

Comment: its full exception and I fixed it by imports right libs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the secret behind import right libraries

```
import Amplify, { API, graphqlOperation } from "aws-amplify";
import PubSub from "@aws-amplify/pubsub";


Amplify.configure(config);
PubSub.configure(config);
API.configure(config);
```

Comment: The whole point of using the modular packages is to not import the monolithic `aws-amplify` package